# User Friendly Way to Display a ComboBox in a WPF DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF application using MVVV; I have a collection of items in an object, one of the properties of the items in the ItemsCollection is an enum, I want the user to be able to edit the properties of the items in the ItemsCollection using a drop down combo box or text field. The collection is displayed in a DataGrid. I am having extreme difficulty getting the combo box to display and allow the user to interact with it and the textbox in a very simple manner (single click, keyboard input). Right now it takes two clicks into a cell to be able to type in the 'name' field where I would want a single click to be able to allow the user to edit the value.

It also takes Three! clicks to expand open the contents of the combobox using the method I have below.

I've tried numerous ways found here on stack overflow but this was the first solution I have found that will even get the enum to populate the combobox and call the set in my property enum

Would someone be able to help me find a way that would allow the user to update entries with a single click on a given row (i.e to click into a text field for editing or click a `ComboBox` to expand it) I've been at this for several hours now and I feel like I'm understanding less and less about how this `DataGrid` works with focus and selected cells/rows. I've got the XAML below here - no code behind.

basically: `DataGrid`, user can click on a cell in the column to select all the text inside the cell for editing, or they can click a `ComboBox` to cause it to drop down with the enums so that they may select a value and apply it to the item with a further click

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="GetEnumValues">
      <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
         <x:Type TypeName="MockItem+ValidItemsType"/>
      </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
   </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid 
   Grid.Column="0" 
   Margin="0,0,0,5" 
   SelectionMode="Single" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedMockItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
   Name="ModelItemDataGrid" 
   MaxHeight="350" 
   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
   ItemsSource="{Binding Model.MockObject.MockItemsCollection}" 
   Height="Auto" 
   HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#CBCBCB"  
   VerticalGridLinesBrush="#CBCBCB" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   IsReadOnly="False" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="Auto"  />
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetEnumValues}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ValidItem}" />
      <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="SelectedItemColumn" Header="Valid Item Type" Width="Auto" >
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Path=ValidItem}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData MockItem}" >
                  <TextBox.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" >
                           <Setter.Value>
                              <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ValidItem, Converter= {StaticResource MockItemValidItemToBackgroundColourConverter1}}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData MockItem}"  />
                           </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                     </Style>
                  </TextBox.Style>
               </TextBox>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why not use an editable combobox? Then you can just use a DataGridTemplateColumn like you have. But also have CellEditingTemplate as well as CellTemplate, and put a combobox in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse,when I get a a chance I'll give this a try and see if I can get anywhere with it

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

this will help you, I had the same problem with you.